Javascript show modal using get ID method returns null
The issue I'm facing is my modals that are connected to my learn more buttons should be opening and displaying text. This works perfectly on my local server in docker. However, when deploying the website to netlify I get the following error when interacting with the button
can't access property "showModal", document.getElementById(...) is null
I have tried having the script file at the bottom of the HTML page and at the top using a defer as I thought it may be executing the JS before the ID existed
Please ask for any other information I will update as much as needed. Still learning the best way to use stack overflow so please be patient with me


// Close all open dialogs
function closeDialogs() {
    const dialogs = document.querySelectorAll('dialog');
    dialogs.forEach(dialog => dialog.close());
}

// Open a specific dialog
function openDialog(id) {
    closeDialogs(); // Ensure all dialogs are closed first
    document.getElementById(id).showModal();
}

// Close a specific dialog
function closeDialog(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).close();
}

// Event listeners for project buttons
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.project-btn.primary').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const dialogId = event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog');
            openDialog(dialogId);
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.x').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const dialog = event.target.closest('dialog');
            closeDialog(dialog.id);
        });
    });
});
<!-- Projects Section -->
<section id="projects">
    <p class="section__text__p1">Browse my Recent</p>
    <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
    <div class="experience-details-container">
        <div class="about-containers">
            <div class="details-container color-container">
                <div class="article-container">
                    <img src="assets/email-client.png" alt="Projects 1" class="project-img">
                </div>
                <h2 class="experience-sub-title project-title">Project One</h2>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com/iO-Academy/2024-mar-sde-email-client-woolly-mammoths'">GitHub</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com'">Live Demo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn primary" onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-1').showModal();">Learn More</button>

                    <dialog id="dialog-1">
                        <h2>Email Client Project</h2>
                        <p>A backend focused project building an email client to show emails in an overview pulling from a fetch request to an API.</p>
                        <p>Please view the live demo.</p>
                        <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-1').close();" aria-label="close" class="x">❌</button>
                    </dialog>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details-container color-container">
                <div class="article-container">
                    <img src="assets/furniture-store.png" alt="Projects 2" class="project-img">
                </div>
                <h2 class="experience-sub-title project-title">Project Two</h2>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com'">GitHub</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com'">Live Demo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn primary" onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-2').showModal();">Learn More</button>

                    <dialog id="dialog-2">
                        <h2>Furniture Store Database Project</h2>
                        <p>A backend focused project handling and building safe and secure databases using queries to sort by ID or various other sorting methods.</p>
                        <p>Please view the live demo.</p>
                        <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-2').close();" aria-label="close" class="x">❌</button>
                    </dialog>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details-container color-container">
                <div class="article-container">
                    <img src="assets/annual-price-toggle.png" alt="Projects 3" class="project-img">
                </div>
                <h2 class="experience-sub-title project-title">Project Three</h2>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com'">GitHub</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com'">Live Demo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-color-2 project-btn primary" onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-3').showModal();">Learn More</button>

                    <dialog id="dialog-3">
                        <h2>Annual Price Toggle Project</h2>
                        <p>A frontend project focused on creating an annual price toggle feature for a subscription-based service.</p>
                        <p>Please view the live demo.</p>
                        <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog-3').close();" aria-label="close" class="x">❌</button>
                    </dialog>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/arrow.png" alt="Arrow Icon" class="icon arrow" onclick="location.href='#contact'" />
</section>




Have you tried to check if the event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog'); value is correctly passed to the function as parameter to openDialog ? Also check if the HTML element is present in the DOM. If this dosen't help to solve the issue double-check that the HTML file being deployed to Netlify is the same as the one you're testing locally.

Thanks Ravina i changed theonclick="document.getElementById('dialog-3').showModal(); to event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog'); and it now works perfectly. Annoying it was that simple i spent way to long troubleshooting that.
